# Brute Forcing Android Lock; How Long Does It Take?

Tags: security

We've seen that [iPhone calculation takes 80 milliseconds per trial](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) to complete. And there's further increasing time penalty with each wrong trial.

Android uses scrypt to generate its Encryption key, so how long does each trial take, and how is this supported by other defenses to hinder brute forcing an encrypted device?

Comment: Encrypted or password/PIN protected ? They are different.

Comment: "...to hinder brute forcing an encrypted device?", as stated, I'm asking about encrypted devices.

Comment: Please link your source of ios

Comment: Linked it under "references".

Comment: While this might not quite answer the question, you should keep this in mind: http://money.cnn.com/2015/09/16/technology/android-hack/